# Entity Framework 'column does not allow nulls'

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Yet again the amazing Entity Framework has failed to make something simple, simple... I have created a really basic set of models, Company, County, User's have a M:1 relationship with Company. So I have an extra table I created called CompanyUsers that I believe will generate the table design I like.

However now I cannot enter a basic user into the database claiming that I cannot have a null UserId even though I am setting the Id.

I understand that my table design is weird, but I may eventually want to switch to a M:M relationship and having this table setup is nice for that. Secondly, having the data in 3 tables makes writing SQL queries easier because of joins.

Exact Error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into
>   column 'UserId', table 'SSI.Database.Context.Software.dbo.Users';
>   column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Seed:

```
var _company = new Company() 
{
    CompanyId=1,
    Name="Company Inc."
};

var _counties = new List<County>() {
    new County(){ Name="Place1" },
    new County(){ Name="Place2"}
};

context.Companies.AddOrUpdate(_company);

var _user = new User() {UserId=1, CompanyId=_company.CompanyId, Company=_company, Name = "John Smith" };


if (context.Counties.Count() == 0)
{
    context.Counties.AddRange(_counties);
}

context.Users.AddOrUpdate(_user);
```

All my models:

Company:

```
public class Company
{

    public Company()
    {
        Users = new List<User>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

User:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }


    public Nullable<int> CompanyId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

CompanyUser Table:

```
public class CompanyUsers
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual User User{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to set the ID for something that's supposed to be auto generated?

Comment: You're using an identity for UserID.  Have you set it up as an identity field in the DB?

Comment: Because leaving it blank still gives me the error.

Comment: If I had to make a wild guess my problem is caused by creating the CompanyUsers table.

Comment: @BaileyMiller Your guess is correct :) So again, why do you need that new many-to-many table in addition to one-to-many that you already have? You shouldn't be preparing to switch - decide now, and migrate later if needed. Keeping both will just cause problems.

Comment: In your entitymodel, select the entity and then the field `UserId`.  On the right side in the properties box there is a property where you can select if null is allowed.

Comment: @IvanStoev I understand and I have cleared up the code so that now everything is in the format for M:M and I will stick with that even if I only actually use 1:M entries.

Comment: Well, if you want to control the exact mapping explicitly, use fluent configuration. If you want to rely on EF conventions, add `public ICollection<CompanyUsers
> CompanyUsers { get; set; }` to **both** `User` and `Company` classes. Currently most likely EF is considering some one-to-one shared PK relationships.

Comment: I don't know what to do here, I have essentially answered the question by messing around with the code, and from the comments.

Answer (score 1):

If your id is automatically generated by database, try add the script below in user class

[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]